# GIMP and Clipping Magic Tool or Plugin

Tags: gimp

I know photoshop has this algo. Is it available in GIMP or another open source tool?

https://clippingmagic.com

Just to clarify, this will be the tool where you highlight what you want in green and what you don't want in red with a little space in between. Then the tool will trace a little yellow line around what you want, and you can adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Gimp's ["Foreground Selection tool"](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-foreground-select.html).

There is also a similar tool in the GMIC plugin.